# Outputs and State of MultiRNNCell in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a stacked MultiRNNCell defined as below :

```
batch_size = 256
rnn_size = 512
keep_prob = 0.5

lstm_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(rnn_size)
lstm_dropout_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_1, output_keep_prob = keep_prob)

lstm_2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(rnn_size)
lstm_dropout_2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_2, output_keep_prob = keep_prob)

stacked_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout_1, lstm_dropout_2])

rnn_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, ques_placeholder)

init_state = stacked_lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
```

In this code, there are two RNN layers. I just want to process the final state of this dynamic RNN. I expected the state to be a 2D tensor of shape `[batch_size, rnn_size*2]`.

The shape of the final_state is 4D - `[2,2,256,512]`

Can someone please explain why am I getting this shape ? Also, how can I process this tensor so that I can pass it through a fully_connected layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the `[2,2,256,512]` shape. But with this piece of code:

```
rnn_size = 512
batch_size = 256
time_size = 5
input_size = 2
keep_prob = 0.5

lstm_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(rnn_size)
lstm_dropout_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_1, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

lstm_2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(rnn_size)

stacked_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout_1, lstm_2])

rnn_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, time_size, input_size])
# Shape of the rnn_inputs is (batch_size, time_size, input_size)

init_state = stacked_lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
rnn_outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm, rnn_inputs, initial_state=init_state)
print(rnn_outputs)
print(final_state)
```

I get the right shape for `run_outputs`: `(batch_size, time_size, rnn_size)`

```
Tensor("rnn/transpose_1:0", shape=(256, 5, 512), dtype=float32)
```

The `final_state` is indeed a pair of `LSTMStateTuple` (for the 2 cells `lstm_dropout_1` and `lstm_2`):

```
(LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_3:0' shape=(256, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_4:0' shape=(256, 512) dtype=float32>),
 LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_5:0' shape=(256, 512) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_6:0' shape=(256, 512) dtype=float32>))
```

as described in the string doc of `tf.nn.dynamic_run`:

```
  # 'outputs' is a tensor of shape [batch_size, max_time, 256]
  # 'state' is a N-tuple where N is the number of LSTMCells containing a
  # tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple for each cell
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The only potential error could be in input to dynamic_rnn which is rnn_inputs. I have a sequence of words that I want to embed before passing it to the dynamic_rnn. Based on your code, the dimensions of this rnn_input needs to be [batch_size, max_sentence_length, emdedding_length]. This is true right now. So I am not sure what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep for comment..
Final state is:

`[depth, lstmtuple.c and .h, batch_size, rnn_size]`