# How to get the states for each step and for each layer in a multilayer RNN using dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a multi-layer RNN with the same setting as in (using MultiRNNCell to wrap up the cells and then use dynamic_rnn to call):

[Outputs and State of MultiRNNCell in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345172/outputs-and-state-of-multirnncell-in-tensorflow)

And as descriped in the above question, the dynamic_rnn returns
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(...)

The outputs only provides outputs I guess from the top layer (because the shape is batch_size x steps x state_size). However, the state return the outputs from each layer (tuple with num_layer elements, each one contains the last state of that layer).

(1) Is there any way that I can assess the outputs from all time steps **for each layer**(not jus the last layer returned by the dynamic_rnn) in a simple way without running a one-step RNN recursively and read the state for each step?

(2) Is the output returned indicated for the last(top) layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation of the `tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell` you should be safe doing the following:

```
cell_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(7, name="gru1")
cell_2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(7, name="gru2")
outputs_1, states_1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_1, X, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs_2, states_2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_2, outputs_1, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    first_layer_outputs = sess.run(outputs_1)
    second_layer_outputs = sess.run(outputs_2)
```

As for the outputs returned by `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`, they are indeed from the top layer if the cell provided is `tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell`.